# Using RecordSource to change form contents

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a method that displays a selected table in a DS view form. The form will be used repeatedly to view different tables, so I figured the easiest way would be to create a form and dynamically change the RecordSource based on the user selection.

I created a form called "frmDisplay" to be used to display the contents of a table to the users. I am trying to use this code to update the form.

```
Private Sub btnViewEntries_Click()

Dim frmDisplay As Form
Dim selection As String

Me.cmboSelection.SetFocus
selection = "tbl" & Me.cmboSelection.Text

Set frmDisplay.RecordSource = selection
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDisplay", acFormDS

End Sub
```

Currently, the code is throwing an "Improper use of property" error when I try to set the RecordSource to the selection made in the combo box.

```
Set frmDisplay.RecordSource = selection
```

I have looked around for a while now, but I cannot seem to find any definitive answer that applies to this example. Most posts that I found were missing the Set keyword...

Does anyone recognize the problem? More importantly, is this even the best way to make this 
work?

Thanks

**_____** EDIT **_____**

I figured it out, see code below.

```
Dim selection As String
Me.cmboSelection.SetFocus
selection = "SELECT * from tbl" & Me.cmboSelection.Text
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDisplay", acDesign
Forms!frmDisplay.Form.RecordSource = selection
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmDisplay", acSaveYes
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDisplay", acFormDS
```

Comment: Have you made sure that `selection` is returning what you're expecting?

Comment: Yes - I ran the code with several selections using "MsgBox (selection)" to ensure the correct value is being returned. The combo box that is sending the input is restricted to only use the existing tables.

Comment: So if your combobox is providing a list of all table names, why are you adding `tbl` to it? Wouldn't that just add `tbl` prefix to the (correct) table name? I also don't think `Set` is the correct syntax. I think `FormName` or `Me` `.RecordSource = X`  is the correct syntax.

Comment: The combo box has the name without the "tbl" prefix. For example, if the user clicked the drop down box and saw "Sparrow", "Fox" and "Elephant", and selected "Sparrow", the actual name of the table is 'tblSparrow' but it is not shown in the combo box for readability. When I run the code without the 'Set' keyword I get "Run-time Error '91', Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Update - when run like 'Me.RecordSource = selection' the form opens, but does not import the data from the table. It simply opens with no records.

Comment: you need to requery it:
    Forms!frmDisplay.Form.Requery

Answer (score 0):

I note you've already provided your answer, but you may find the following helpful.

If you have a main form with the controls `cmboSelection` and `btnViewEntries` then add a subform control and call it `fsbDisplay`. Don't put anything in this subform, leave it unbound.

Now try the following one-liner:

```
Private Sub btnViewEntries_Click()

    fsbDisplay.SourceObject = "Table.tbl" & cmboSelection.Value

End Sub
```

The advantage of this method is that you can use it to call up any table or query (prefix with `Query.` instead of `Table.`) and the fields shown are dynamically created.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll be sure to try it out.